# Implementation of Round Robin in Scala

Tags: java, scala, operating-system, scheduling, round-robin

i have implemented Round Robin Algorithm with fixed time quantum in Scala. Code is working fine with desired output but in a specific case code is not giving desirable results.

Let I have five processes **p0,p1,p2,p3,p4** with arrival time **3,0,1,9,6** and Burst time **1,2,6,7,9** respectively and set (quantum time) **q=3**.
In first iteration of do-while loop,my code will execute **p1,p2**. In second iteration of loop it will now execute all processes. but execution is this way is not desired one.

I want execution in this way. In first iteration of do-while loop, When code start execution it will first check arrival time of p0 that is not 0 (not less than or equal to variable tracker as initial value of tracker = 0). Code will now execute p1 as its arrival time is 0. When p1 completes its execution,p2 will be arrived, so p2 will be executed. after execution of p2 ,p0 is arrived (as tracker = 5 at this point and arrival time of p0 = 4) , so now code should execute p0 and than should execute other processes. Mean execution should be in this sequence **p1,p2,p0,p4,p3** in first iteration of do-while loop and than go for second iteration based on given condition.

**Note**: Sorting process based on arrival time is not solution according to my need. Processes are sorted based on their Burst time.
My code is

```
def RoundRobin(n: Int, data: Array[Array[Double]]): Unit = {
 var arr = data.map(_.map(identity))  // first column of arr holds arrival time and second column holds Burst time.
 val q = 3.0
 val wt = new Array[Double](n) // wt is waiting time
 val a = new Array[Double](n)  

 var sum = 0.0
 for (i <- 0 to n - 1) {
  a(i) = arr(i)(1)
 }
 for (i <- 0 to n - 1) {
  wt(i) = 0
 }
 var tracker = 0.0  // Used for arrival time comparision
 do {
  arr = arr.sortBy(x => x(1))   //sort based on Burst time 
  for (i <- 0 to arr.size - 1) {
    if (tracker >= arr(i)(0))  // check if tracker is greater is greater than or equal to Arrival Time of process i
    {
      if (arr(i)(1) > q) {    //if Burst time > quantum time
        arr(i)(1) -= q        // decrement burst time of process i by q (quantum time) unit of time
        tracker = tracker + q // increment value of tracker by q unit of time
        for (j <- 0 to arr.size - 1) {
          if ((j != i) && (arr(j)(1) != 0))
            wt(j) += q        // increment waiting time of process j by q (quantum time)
        }
      }
      else {
        for (j <- 0 to arr.size - 1) {
          if ((j != i) && (arr(j)(1) != 0)) {
            wt(j) += arr(i)(1)    // increment waiting time of process j by rem aining burst time of i
          }
        }
        tracker = tracker + arr(i)(1) // increment value of tracker by burst time of process
        arr(i)(1) = 0  // set burst time of process i = 0 as process completed execution
      }
    }
    else {

      if (i == arr.length - 1) { // if all processes have been traversed that is value of i == length of list than increment tracker by 1
        tracker = tracker + 1
      }

    }
  }
  sum = 0.0
  for (i <- 0 to arr.length - 1)
    sum = sum + arr(i)(1)
 } while (sum != 0)
 var avg_wt = 0.0  //wt is waiting time
 var avg_tat = 0.0 // tat is Turn around time
 for (j <- 0 to n - 1) {
  wt(j) = wt(j) - arr(j)(0)
  if(wt(j) < 0){
    wt(j)=0.0
  }
 }
 for (j <- 0 to n - 1) {
  avg_wt = avg_wt + wt(j);
  avg_tat = avg_tat + wt(j) + a(j) // TaT = WT + BT
 }
 println(" total waiting time= " + avg_wt  + " Total turn around time= " + avg_tat )
 println(" average waiting time= " + (avg_wt / n) + " Average turn around time= " + (avg_tat / n))
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 println("Enter number of process:");
 val n = scala.io.StdIn.readInt();  //  n is number of processes
 var array: Array[Array[Double]] = Array.ofDim(n, 2)

//arrival time
 array(0)(0) = 3
 array(1)(0) = 0
 array(2)(0) = 1
 array(3)(0) = 9
 array(4)(0) = 6

//Burst time
 array(0)(1) = 1
 array(1)(1) = 2
 array(2)(1) = 6
 array(3)(1) = 7
 array(4)(1) = 9

 RoundRobin(n,array)
 }
```

Comment: @jwvh data.map(_.map(identity)) if not used, empty 2D Array will be passed to Roundrobin method from main

Comment: What's the difference between that and `var arr = data`?

Comment: when I used **var arr = data** data of **data** is not passed to **arr**. I do not know what is reason. Than I used **data.map(_.map(identity))**

Comment: @jwvh `Array` is mutable so `map(map(identity))` is making a two-level copy.

Comment: I would start by converting this declarative style into functional code, which is what Scala is designed for. Use `map` or `fold` rather than looping through indices, and think about creating new data from old rather than mutating data in-place.

Comment: @Tim i am new to Scala and have beginner level  knowledge about writing functional code in Scala. If you write this in functional style it will be very help full for me.

Comment: @Tim I am waiting for solution as said by you in comments